# how to change size of cell image in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uiimageview, cgrect

I have a cell with an image.  I am trying to change the size of the image in the cell programmatically like this:

```
cell.myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_icon"];
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
[self imageWithImage:cell.goalTypeImage.image scaledToSize:size];
```

Image with size looks like this:

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image
              scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

I also tried this which does not work:

```
cell.myImage.frame = CGRectMake(
cell.myImage.frame.origin.x,
cell.myImage.frame.origin.y, 50, 50);
cell.myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"];
```

Does anyone know why the image is NOT changing size?

Comment: How does that compile? You've got an extra semicolon typo on the end of your imageWithImage method definition.

Comment: The size of the image has changed, but the size of the `UIImageView` is not.

Comment: You don't use the return value from `imageWithImage:scaledToSize:`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with the returned image. This should work:

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
cell.myImage.image = [self imageWithImage:cell.goalTypeImage.image scaledToSize:size];
```

Comment: Then you have a problem elsewhere in your code, @Atma.

Comment: its a custom cell, does that matter?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use the native image of UITableViewCell like this :

```
cell.imageView.image = myImage;
```

And then you can resize it :

```
cell.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(widthScale, heightScale);
```

You have some interesting UITableViewCell's properties like textLabel, detailTextLabel, and imageView.

Comment: have you create a custom table view cell with custom view ? or it's the default UITableViewCell of tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: did you connect the uiimage in the  interface builder to you myImage property ?